# Link with -rpath=/usr/local/lib works, -rapth=$ORIGIN does not

Tags: linux, ld, gcc9

I am working on an embedded Linux target, gcc 9.2. If I link with `-rpath=/usr/local/lib`, the *readelf* utility shows me the `RPATH` entry, as expected. If I link with `-rpath=$ORIGIN`, *readelf* shows no `RAPTH`, and nothing involving `ORIGIN`. The link command appears to be correct: `x86_64-poky-linux-g++ ... -Xlinker -rpath=$ORIGIN ...`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to quote `$ORIGIN`?

Comment: Like this? `x86_64-poky-linux-g++ ... -rpath="$ORIGIN" ...` Didn't change anything, I'm afraid.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that I'm cross-compiling in an Eclipse CDT Managed Build project; hence I had to specify `-rpath=$$ORIGIN` in the "C/C++ Build > Settings > Cross G++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Other options" section. I am showing the link command as it appears in the console.

Comment: I meant single quotes

Comment: Hot diggity! `x86_64-poky-linux-g++ ... -Xlinker -rpath='$ORIGIN' ...` did the trick. Could you explain? Does the passage through g++ to the linker do some substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply typing `$ORIGN` was causing your shell to expand the variable before the value was passed to the linker. Since you likely had no `ORIGIN` environment variable, you were getting nothing.

You need to prevent shell expansion so that `$ORIGIN` literally is passed to the linker - to do that, one uses single quotes. Double quotes won't work because variables are interpolated in double quotes.